# Using jQuery to make hovering html windows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I'm trying to make an html window appear over an html webpage that I already have in the background.  Essentially I need the html window hovering above the current webpage.  I wanted it to look something like the following:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-message

Where you'll notice the window appears hovering over the actual webpage and has an okay button and a cancel X button.  I attempted to do this by modifying the source code given to me in that page, and adapting it for my own use.  My first step in doing this was to copy the source code and put it in a new html file.  After I did that I clicked on the html file expecting to see the same example as on the website I linked above.  Instead of seeing that, I saw only this:

[image]

Which leads me to believe that one of the CSS files is missing.  I suspect that the file that is missing is contained in this line of code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

However I do not know for sure.  At this point I really just want to get my html file to open up and look just like the example in the link.  If someone could tell me how to do that or where to locate the missing css file, I would really appreciate it.  Thanks.

Comment: Download jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/download/) and fix all resource dependencies that you have.

Comment: Thanks.  After I download and extract the files, do I just drop my html file into the jquery folder? Or do I have to implement it in some other way?

Comment: Edit that HTML file and give the correct resource relative paths for the CSS and JS files that it depends on.

Comment: click on  view source and copy all code

Comment: I clicked view source and copied all the code.  I guess i'm just wondering why it doesn't work with some of the files when the method coded to link the files were through web addresses.  I thought the web addresses would work for describing the file paths

Comment: You can also accomplish this basic idea using a lightbox.  This way you can customize the internal html any way you want.  Just put a hidden div at the end of your DOM, right before the /body tag.  Use position:absolute, set the left and top where you want it, and use show/hide.